# Interesting processing time results

Tags: c++, runtime

I've made a small application that averages the numbers between 1 and 1000000. It's not hard to see (using a very basic algebraic formula) that the average is 500000.5 but this was more of a project in learning C++ than anything else.

Anyway, I made clock variables that were designed to find the amount of clock steps required for the application to run. When I first ran the script, it said that it took 3770000 clock steps, but every time that I've run it since then, it's taken "0.0" seconds...

I've attached my code at the bottom.

Either a.) It's saved the variables from the first time I ran it, and it's just running quickly to the answer...
or b.) something is wrong with how I'm declaring the time variables.

Regardless... it doesn't make sense.

Any help would be appreciated.

FYI (I'm running this through a Linux computer, not sure if that matters)

```
double avg (int arr[], int beg, int end)
{
    int nums = end - beg + 1;

    double sum = 0.0;

    for(int i = beg; i <= end; i++)
    {
        sum += arr[i];
    }   

    //for(int p = 0; p < nums*10000; p ++){}

    return sum/nums;

}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) 
{ 
    int nums = 1000000;//atoi(argv[0]);
    int myarray[nums];

    double timediff;

    //printf("Arg is: %d\n",argv[0]);
    printf("Nums is: %d\n",nums);

    clock_t begin_time = clock();

    for(int i = 0; i < nums; i++)
    {
        myarray[i] = i+1;
    }

    double average = avg(myarray, 0, nums - 1);

    printf("%f\n",average); 

    clock_t end_time = clock();

    timediff = (double) difftime(end_time, begin_time);

    printf("Time to Average: %f\n", timediff);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: It probably runs so fast that it says `0.0 seconds`.

Comment: I would totally expect the local 4MB array to cause a stack overflow.

Comment: `difftime()` takes to time_ts according to cplusplus.com, not clock_ts, which have a much higher resolution. Find out how often clock_t ticks on your machine and then diff the clock_ts yourself.

Comment: It's not printing in the unit of seconds, and either way, that doesn't answer the question of why it originally produces a result > 0 then, subsequently always takes 0 time steps

Comment: @user2584876: I think you probably changed the code.  For this code to print a time of 3770000, you would have had to wait ~44 days for it to finish.

Comment: @ Timo

When I just subtract begin_time from end_time, I oddly enough get the same answer I do for my average...

Comment: @MooingDuck 

I made one small change since then, I instantiated a double time_diff at the beginning of the script instead of when calculating difftime(...)

Even then, the results from that first time I ran it (even before that change) it always produced 0.0 as the number of time steps

Comment: and based on your own observation how time in sec the program took to run ? if it's too quick try to call 10x the average function.

Comment: @alexbuisson
It takes about 2 seconds to run, I even tried putting an extraneous loop into the average function to slow it down... just an empty loop that runs 10,000,000,000 times, it slowed it down considerably, but the time to average still comes out to be my average... (after edits made via TimoGeusch 's suggestion

Comment: @user2584876: If the code you're testing isn't the code in the question here, we won't be able to help much.

Comment: [Apperently Linux's `clock()` call is only accurate to 100th of a second on this machine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=d8bb8ba9f44ea11a4ba7cb9d01e7470b-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are measuring the I/O operation too (printf), that depends on external factors and might be affecting the run time. Also, clock() might not be as precise as needed to measure such a small task - look into higher resolution functions such as clock_get_time(). Even then, other processes might affect the run time by generating page fault interrupts and occupying the memory BUS, etc. So this kind of fluctuation is not abnormal at all.

Answer (score 0):

[On the machine I tested](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=d8bb8ba9f44ea11a4ba7cb9d01e7470b-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51), Linux's `clock` call was only accurate to 1/100th of a second.  If your code runs in less than 0.01 seconds, it will usually say zero seconds have passed.  Also, I ran your program a total of 50 times in .13 seconds, so I find it suspicous that you claim it takes 2 seconds to run it once on your computer.

Your code incorrectly uses the `difftime`, which may display incorrect output as well if clock says time did pass.

I'd guess that the first timing you got was with different code than that posted in this question, becase I can't think of any way the code in this question could produce a time of 3770000.

Finally, benchmarking is hard, and your code has several benchmarking mistakes:

- You're timing how long it takes to (1) fill an array, (2) calculate an average, (3) format the result string (4) make an OS call (slow) that prints said string in the right language/font/colo/etc, which is especially slow.
- You're attempting to time a task which takes less than a hundredth of a second, which is WAY too small for any accurate measurement.

[Here is my take on your code, measuring that the average takes ~0.001968 seconds on this machine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=ad36343dee12a10f3be0b398765f03e6-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51).

Comment: Whether or not I followed the best practices guide for benchmarking, I was merely trying to get a reference frame, not necessarily accurate results.

I reproduced this code in a parallel design and was interested in just seeing any improvement of runtime.

This was my first attempt, but I'm currently working on a more involved issue so that I can better see the run-time improvements.

Comment: If it's not somewhat accurate, it makes a pretty lousy frame.  Benchmarking is hard, _because if people do what you did, bad things have been known to result_.  You end up thinking your code is far faster or slower than it actually is.

Comment: I appreciate your insights. I hope that all of the self gratification you've gotten out of being condescending has made your probably unsatisfactory existence that much more tolerable.

Thanks,